# Java8 Stream syntax to create a list of pojos

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to learn streaming syntax and I'm struggling to convert some for loops into a stream. If this is inappropriate here let me know and I'll delete.

Essentially I have a list of pojo's (with nested pojos) which I'm using to create a new list of different pojo's
(entity to model).

The (working) for loop is like this

```
for (Pojo1 p1 : pojo1.getPojo1List())
{
   List <String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
   for (Pojo2 p2 : p1.GetPojo2List())
   {
      stringList.add(p2.getText());
   } 

   Pojo3 p3 = new Pojo3(p1.getMember1(), p1.getMember2(), stringList);
}
```

I have replace the inner loop with a stream pipeline giving

```
for (Pojo1 p1 : pojo1.getPojo1List())
{
    List <String> stringList = p1.GetPojo2List().stream().map(Pojo2::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());

    Pojo3 p3 = new Pojo3(p1.getMember1(), p1.getMember2(), stringList);
```

}

This is working properly.

I would now like to replace the first loop though and I'm struggling to work out which way to go to do this. I started with something like this

```
pojo1.getPojo1List().stream().forEach(p1 -> new Pojo3(p1.getMember1(), p1.getMember2(), [stream from above])
```

This is not working but before I play with it too much it occurred to me that as foreach is a terminal operator this approach is probably wrong as I wouldn't be able to collect the pojos I create (?)

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Question, why is your method called `GetPojo2List`? In Java, methods are **always** in `camelCase` - no excuses, no exceptions. Please update your code.

Comment: Why did you insert a `.sorted()` step that doesn’t exist in your former program logic? If you change the requirements in the process, the posted old code isn’t helpful anymore, to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: because the code evolved between loop and stream.  Will delete the sorted and update to camel case.

Comment: Your `forEach` code doesn’t work, because you are ignorant towards the correct spelling of methods, but Java is not. Besides, it does exactly what your original loop does, create `Pojo3` instances and forget about them. If you want to collect them into a `List`, well, you already know how to do that (hint: the way you do it already for the inner operation, `map(…).collect(Collectors.toList())`).

Comment: Okay forEach casing was typo in the question.  Honestly just thought this would be trivial for someone with a lot of java8 experience but accept the devil is in the detail.   Will look further at the map.  Cheers (I think!).

Comment: It’s as trivial as nesting two `map(…).collect(Collectors.toList())` operations, i.e. `List<Pojo3> result=pojo1.getPojo1List().stream() .map(p1 -> new Pojo3(p1.getMember1(), p1.getMember2(), p1.GetPojo2List().stream().map(Pojo2::getText).collect(Collectors.toList()) ).collect(Collectors.toList());`. The nested collection is unavoidable, because your `Pojo3` constructor *requires* a `List`.

Comment: Thanks I understand now ...  get there eventually